# Is $( P(X), *)$ a group if: 1. $A*B = A \cup B$ and 2. $A*B = A \cap B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and let $P(X)$ be the set of all subsets of $X$. Is $( P(X), *)$ a group if:

1. $A*B = A \cup B$
2. $A*B = A \cap B$

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a topological space. A topological space is closed under the operations of union and intersection (consists of the subsets of a specific set $S$).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

We have $A\cup A = A\cap A = A$ for all $A$. But in a group, the only idempotent element is the identity:

Assume $a^2=a$. Then we have
$$a = a1 = a(aa^{-1}) = a^2a^{-1} = aa^{-1} = 1$$

Therefore the only group where each element is idempotent is the trivial group, which consists of only the neutral element.

Now there is exactly one case where $P(X)$ contains exactly one element: If $X$ is the empty set. And indeed, in this special case, it is easily checked that both $\cup$ and $\cap$ are group operations.

But as soon as $X$ is not the empty set, you don't get a group.

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer, @user719193. I suggest you accept it once you understand it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a group in the both cases. There are no inverses in case 1 ($\lbrace\rbrace$ is the identity). There are no **unique** identity element in case 2 (identity for every element is itself).

But power set is closed under symmetric difference. So you should better consider this.

Comment: The identity is defined to be the same for all sets, and there is indeed an indentity in case 2, namely $X$. The identity is unique (identities always are). Now what *is* true is that all elements are idempotent, which is not possible in a group (except for the trivial group); but that doesn't make those elements identities.

Comment: Yeah, true. $x \cdot x = x$ only when $x = e$ by the existence of inverses. The fact that some element other than identity possesses this property is contradictory. Hence case 2 is no group.

Answer (score 1):

Both operations are associative, so we just need to check for a unit and an inverse operation.

In Case 1, the unit $E$ would have to satisfy $A\cup E=A$ for all $A\subset X$.  The only possible thing that could satisfy this is $E=\emptyset$.  However, there could be no inverse function that satisfies $A\cup f(A)=\emptyset$ for all $A\subset X$, so this cannot be made into a group.

Similarly, in Case 2 the only possible unit is $E=X$, but there could be no inverse function that satisfies $A\cap f(A)=X$ for all $A\subset X$.  Therefore, both operations endow $P(X)$ with the structure of a monoid that cannot be made into a group.